# Object Not Moving Until Bool is True?

Tags: c#

I want my game so when the game starts, it will say "Don't Touch The Walls!" And then count down to 0, then disappear. i also want it so that the player can't move until it hits 0. It is pacman-esque, so the player is always moving. The text disappears when the counter hits 0, yet the player moves before this happens.
Code:

```
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour {
float speed = 0.1f;
int direction = 0;
public GameObject eventHandler;
private EventStuff eventHandlerScript;
public bool start = false;






// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    eventHandlerScript = eventHandler.GetComponent<EventStuff>();
    start = eventHandlerScript.gameStart;


}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    start = eventHandlerScript.gameStart;
    if (start = true) {
        //The movement Code is here
    }


}
```

}

The Invisible Data Handler:

```
public class EventStuff : MonoBehaviour {
public Text DontTouch;
public Text Counter;
public float timer = 1f;
public bool gameStart = false;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    timer++;
    if (timer < 60) {
        Debug.Log ("3");
    } else if (timer < 120) {
        Counter.text = ("2");
        Debug.Log ("2");
    } else if (timer < 180) {
        Counter.text = ("1");
        Debug.Log ("1");
    }
    else if(timer > 180) {

    Destroy(Counter);
    Destroy(DontTouch);
        gameStart = true;
        Debug.Log ("start!");
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if (start = true) {
```

you should write

```
if (start == true) {
```

or better simply

```
if (start) {
```

Comment: I just did this but now the player just doesn't move, even after the counter hits 0.